# How to add the following images on my github's project description?

Tags: node.js, github

I want to add some images on my github's project description as following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

how to generate these images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Those come from one of the services** such as https://travis-ci.org/ build service

Here related travis-ci documentation:

http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/status-images/